# Structuring two first authors equal contribution in computer science publication

Tags: publications, authorship

Sorry if this is a naive question. We tried finding guidelines, but have failed to find concrete advice.

There are N authors (where N>2) in our publication. Two authors have equal contribution. We are aware of the custom of putting an asterisk and writing a footnote about equal contribution.

However, while arranging the names of authors with equal contribution, how should they be arranged – alphabetically by last name? For instance, if the names are John Foe and Jane Doe, should they be arranged alphabetically by last name: Jane Doe*, John Foe*?

Comment: You've given us a choice of one.

Comment: Typically ties, or approximate ties, are broken alphabetically by surname, yes.